# Can't find "raylib.dll"

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, raylib

I'm trying to use the raylib on Visual Studio 2019, I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Create-Visual-Studio-Project) 
I can build without anywarning, but when I run my program a error windows saying that it can't find "raylib.dll" apear. What can I do to solve this ?

Comment: VS 2017 template has Release/Debug.dll configurations which create dll itself. Maybe try look into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my issue by placing the raylib.dll that's in [this raylib distribution](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/releases/download/2.6.0/raylib-2.6.0-Win64-msvc15.zip) in the folder where my executable is build